# Looping through a n-dimensional array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I have a generic multidimensional array having different dimensions. I need to loop through it in order to save for each element the relative array of indices and the relative value.

In the case of an array of two dimensions, let's say 4 and 5, it would be trivial:

```
        var d1 = 4;
        var d2 = 5;
        var array = Array.CreateInstance(typeof (int), new[] {d1, d2});

        //...
        // code for populating array
        //...

        for (int i = 0; i < d1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < d2; j++)
            {
                var value = array.GetValue(new[] { i, j });
                var indices = new[] {i, j};
            }
        }
```

But I need to do the same thing with an array of n different dimensions. 
How can I achieve it? Do I need to implement a recursive function?

Comment: Are you already given an `n` dimensional array and just need to write the code for iterating over it?

Comment: Yes, the n dimensional array is given. I need to iterate over it, independently from the number and the size of its dimensions.

Comment: Given an `n` dimensional array, you can just do a flat iteration through the array and use modulo operators to figure out what index you're at.

Comment: Thanks Asad for the answer. Could you please write an example? I am not sure how to use modulo operators for getting both the value and the index.

Comment: Yup, working on it now.

Comment: Can I assume that the lower bound in each dimension is 0 and the upper bound is simply the dimension?

Comment: This assumption is fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visiting all elements in a multidimensional array is not difficult. You can simply do a flat iteration through the entire array with a single index. The tricky part is mapping this single index to the corresponding multidimensional coordinates.

In general, given a matrix with size vector `D`, the `i`th single indexed element of this matrix has a coordinate vector `C_i`, such that:

[image]

For `0 <= n < size(D)`.

Implementing this, the `IndexToCoordinates` method is:

```
static int[] IndexToCoordinates(int i, Array arr)
{
    var dims = Enumerable.Range(0, arr.Rank)
        .Select(arr.GetLength)
        .ToArray();

    Func<int, int, int> product = (i1, i2) => i1 * i2;

    return dims.Select((d, n) => (i/dims.Take(n).Aggregate(1, product))%d).ToArray();
}
```

Now, for example, if you wanted to visit every item in a multidimensional array and output its coordinates, you could do:

```
static void OutputAllArrayIndices(Array arr)
{
    var i = 0;

    foreach (int item in arr)
    {
        var coords = IndexToCoordinates(i++, arr);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", coords));
    }
}
```

Running `OutputAllArrayIndices(new int[3, 2, 4])` then produces:

```
0, 0, 0
1, 0, 0
2, 0, 0
3, 0, 0
0, 1, 0
1, 1, 0
2, 1, 0
3, 1, 0
0, 0, 1
1, 0, 1
2, 0, 1
3, 0, 1
0, 1, 1
1, 1, 1
2, 1, 1
3, 1, 1
0, 0, 2
1, 0, 2
2, 0, 2
3, 0, 2
0, 1, 2
1, 1, 2
2, 1, 2
3, 1, 2
```

Comment: Thanks Asad. Your code is really fine, even if I think the dimensions should not be reversed, because the array of the coordinates is wrongly reversed. You can also notice this behavior in the output you posted.